# AS3 Error with POST but not with GET (#2032 Stream Error)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air

This *should* be simple. I'm trying to send POST data to a server and have written a custom package for it as follows:

```
package com.cron {
import flash.events.*
import flash.net.*

public class Mail {
    var scriptURL = "http://www.[mydomain].com/scripts/flashmail.php";
    var pass = '[mypassword]'
    var productName = '[myProduct]'
    var fromemail = 'noreply@[mydomain].com'
    var scriptLoader,scriptRequest,scriptVars,onComplete

    public function Mail(ProductName=null, Fromemail=null, OnComplete=null, ScriptURL=null, Pass=null) {
        //SET PARAMS:
        scriptURL = (ScriptURL ? ScriptURL : scriptURL)
        productName = (ProductName ? ProductName : productName)
        fromemail = (Fromemail ? Fromemail : fromemail)
        pass = (Pass ? Pass : pass)
        onComplete = OnComplete ? OnComplete : null
        //SETUP CLASS:
        scriptRequest = new URLRequest(scriptURL);
        scriptLoader = new URLLoader();
        scriptVars = new URLVariables();
    }

    public function sendmail(toemail,subject,msg){
         
        scriptLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, handleLoadSuccessful);
        scriptLoader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, handleLoadError);
        scriptLoader.addEventListener(HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_STATUS, handleLoadError);
         
        scriptVars.pass = pass;
        scriptVars.productname = productName;
        scriptVars.toemail = toemail;
        scriptVars.subject = subject;
        scriptVars.msg = msg;
        scriptVars.fromemail = fromemail;
        //trace(scriptVars)

        scriptRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST; 
        scriptRequest.data = scriptVars;

        G.traceObj(scriptRequest) 

        scriptLoader.load(scriptRequest);
        trace("MAIL: Sending mail to "+toemail)
    }

    private function handleLoadSuccessful($evt:Event):void{
        if(String(scriptLoader.data) != '1'){
            trace("MAIL: Error with script:")
            trace(scriptLoader.data)
            if(onComplete) onComplete(0);
            return;
        }else{
            trace('MAIL: Sent successfully')
            if(onComplete) onComplete(1);
        }

    }
     
    private function handleLoadError($evt):void{
        trace("MAIL: Connection Failed with error: "+$evt);
        if(onComplete) onComplete(0);
    }
}

}
```

If I change `URLRequestMethod.POST` to `URLRequestMethod.GET`, this all works great. However, using POST, I get the following errors:

```
MAIL: Connection Failed with error: [HTTPStatusEvent type="httpStatus" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2 status=0 responseURL=null]
MAIL: Connection Failed with error: [IOErrorEvent type="ioError" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2 text="Error #2032: Stream Error. URL: http://www.[myDomain].com/scripts/flashmail.php"]
```

Bizzarely, if I upload this to my server, it works fine! It just refuses to work with a local swf or packaged AIR app. **I need to deploy this on Android** so it's crucial I get it working locally.

Comment: What is [Mydomain] here? is it a valid domain?

Comment: Yes, it's just my server. This exact script works perfectly when I switch it to GET

Comment: ok first you need to add folder to trusted location from [Truested Location Settings](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlayer/LSM/WS6aa5ec234ff3f285139dc56112e3786b68c-7ff0.html) which contains your swf ... and second your flashMail.php should handle POST data too but looks like it is... however i hope it is handling with efficient way

Comment: Thanks, I was under the impression what swfs running in the Flash IDE weren't subject to the trusted location sandbox? This has to be deployed on Android anyway so that can't be the solution.

The server script is configured for POST (this script works fine when I upload it to the server). It doesnt look like the connection gets that far. See `http status = 0` in the error message? It's got to be a security thing

Comment: did you try on android for testing ? all have different security settings for different platforms ... for deploying android you should add permission(<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />) to android manifest in -app.xml

Comment: I set the INTERNET permission in the flash android publish settings. Do I need to do it somewhere else also?

Comment: no did you try your test release ".apk" on your device ?

Comment: Sure did - it actually stopped all code below it on android. It really feels like a security issue

Comment: Have you figured it out? I see lots of #2032 errors in my air app as well, when I make ```POST``` requests.

Comment: No sorry - I actually ended up working around this so it was never resolved. If you figure it out report back!

Answer (score 0):

```
btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,handler);
function handler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
        var url:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
        url.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;
        var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://www.[myDomain].com/scripts/flashmail.php");
        var rv:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
        rv.user_ = user_.text;
        request.data = rv;
        request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
        url.load(request);
        url.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,eventComplete);
        url.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR,ioerror);
        function eventComplete(e:Event):void
        {
            if (e.target.data.success == "ok")
            {
                trace('result:' + e.target.data.success2);
            }
            else
            {
                trace('no result');
            }
        }
}
function ioerror(e:Event):void
{
    trace("Connection Error");
}
```