# Actionscript Firebase POSTing, Error #2032

Tags: actionscript-3, rest, firebase

I am trying to POST to my firebase account, but I can't seem to figure out why it's not letting me. I can  switch the POST to a GET and trace out the data I'm trying to get, but when I POST I get en error.

Code:

```css
package 
{
    import flash.display.Loader;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.IOErrorEvent;
    import flash.net.URLLoader;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.net.URLRequestMethod;
    import flash.net.URLVariables;
    import flash.net.navigateToURL;
    import flash.net.URLLoaderDataFormat;
    //import flash.system.Security;

    /**
     * ...
     * @author M
     */
    public class FireBaseConnector 
    {

        public function FireBaseConnector() 
        {
            //Security.loadPolicyFile("https://demo.firebaseio-demo.com/crossdomain.xml");

            trace("trying to post");
            var url:String = 'https://[myURL].firebaseio.com/userData.json';

            var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);

            var variables:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
            variables.name = "alan"
            req.data = variables;
            req.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;         

            var l:URLLoader = new URLLoader()
            //l.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.TEXT;
            l.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onError);
            l.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, handleResults);          

            l.load(req);    
        }

        public function onError(e:IOErrorEvent):void {
            trace("Error! " + e.text);
        }

        public function handleResults(e:Event):void {
            trace("response" + e.target.data as String);
        }

    }

}
```

My output is:

```
[Starting debug session with FDB]
running
trying to post
Error! Error #2032: Stream Error. URL: https://resplendent-fire-2464.firebaseio.com/userData/.json
closing time!
closing time!
```

If i switch to GET my output is:

```
[Starting debug session with FDB]
running
trying to post
response{"dave":{"id":"678","name":"dave"},"mike":{"name":"mike"},"miles":{"id":"456","name":"miles"}}
closing time!
closing time!
```

That tells me I have the url right, but I have some permissions problem or something when trying to post. Maybe I have the variables sending improperly? I've made sure my Flash debugger is on the accepted app list in my Firewall.

I'm running Windows 10 and FlashDevelop JRE 1.6 Flex 4.6 Air 18

Comment: What happens if you send the POST request from some other application, your browser for example.

Comment: I've posted here before in python using a firebase lib. I'll try a post again tonight to verify.

Comment: When I POST from postman, the data does get added to my database.

Comment: I see this question now: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19429525/as3-error-with-post-but-not-with-get-2032-stream-error?rq=1

I will see if it's a trusted location problem. I'm away from my developer computer now, but will check Monday.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlayer/LSM/WS6aa5ec234ff3f285139dc56112e3786b68c-7ff0.html#WS6aa5ec234ff3f285139dc56112e3786b68c-7fea

Comment: I added my SDK folder, by project folder, and my Flash Debugger folder to the Trusted Locations in Flash settings per the adobe link above and it did not work either. Did not work.

Additionally, I added some text fields to print stuff out and hosted this on my dropbox which has web hosting (some old feature I got grandfathered in that's now premium or something). I see that it's running, and again I get proper results on a GET but not a POST.

The only difference is on dropbox the error.test is "Error #2032" and locally it's "Error #2032: Stream Error. URL: [url]/userData.json"

Answer (score 1):

To send a POST request to the Firebase REST API you need to send the data JSON encoded:

```
var urlVars:Object = new Object();
urlVars.name = nameTxt.text;
urlVars.lastname = lastNameTxt.text;

var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(FIREBASEURL);
request.data = JSON.stringify(urlVars);
request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;

var firebaseLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
firebaseLoader.addEventListener(flash.events.Event.COMPLETE, function():void
{
    trace(firebaseLoader.data);
});
firebaseLoader.load(request);
```

Answer (score 0):

I try this code can work

```
import flash.net.URLLoader;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.events.Event;

var urlVars:Object = new Object();
urlVars.name = "111111";

var url:URLLoader=new URLLoader();
var hdr:URLRequestHeader = new URLRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest( "https://[myURL].firebaseio.com/userData.json" );
req.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
req.data = JSON.stringify(urlVars);
url.load(req);
url.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,urlCompelte)

function urlCompelte(e:Event){
    trace(e.target.data);//{"name":"-Ka6PGZc_hY-sfJJqeVS"}
}
```